# List values in MongoDB aggregation pipeline belonging to different documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I got this result coming from an Aggregation pipeline I did:

```
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2015-05-14T08:22:09.441Z"),
    "values" : {
        "v1_min" : 15.872267760931187,
        "v1" : 15.909139078185774,
        "v1_max" : 20.6420184124931776
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2015-05-13T08:22:09.441Z"),
    "values" : {
        "v1_min" : 2.872263320931187,
        "v1" : 7.909132898185774,
        "v1_max" :44.6498764124931776
    }
},
{...}
```

do you think it's possible to get a structure like this one

```
{
        "_id" : [ISODate("2015-05-14T08:22:09.441Z"),ISODate("2015-05-13T08:22:09.441Z")]
        "values" : {
            "v1_min" : [15.872267760931187, 2.872263320931187],
            "v1" : [15.909139078185774, 7.909132898185774]
            "v1_max" : [2.6420184124931776, 44.6498764124931776]
        }
}
```

adding some others stages to my aggregation pipelines?

If so, how would you do?

I'd not like to handle this via code because I think MongoDB aggregation framework is faster and should do better than me.

Comment: Two questions: (1) is the data order significant in the various output arrays (2) what about duplicated values ? Does they need to be emitted multiple times ?

Comment: Answer for both questions is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible indeed. The following aggregation pipeline will achieve the desired output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "ids": {
                "$addToSet": "$_id"
            },
            "v1_min": {
                "$push": "$values.v1_min"
            },
            "v1": {
                "$push": "$values.v1"
            },
            "v1_max": {
                "$push": "$values.v1_max"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$ids",
            "values": {
                "v1_min": "$v1_min",
                "v1": "$v1",
                "v1_max": "$v1_max"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

---

-- **EDIT** --

Use [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push) instead of [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet) as the latter will only add the element if and only if the final array does not contain the element itself. (Thanks to @SylvainLeroux for the positive contributions)

Comment: Worth mentioning that `$addToSet` cannot guarantee the various data to be in their corresponding position. i.e.: the "first" v1_min does not necessary belong to the "first" _id. From the doc: ["$addToSet does not guarantee a particular ordering of elements in the modified set."](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#behavior)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Not sure about the order of elements in the resulting array, perhaps the OP would shed more light on that?

Comment: BTW, is there any benefit here in using `$addToSet` instead of `$push` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux **`$addToSet`** does not add an element to a given array if it already contains it, on the other hand **`$push`** will add the given object to the field whether it exists or not. For distinct array elements one would go for the former and disregarding duplicates then the latter would suffice. That as well ultimately depends on what the OP requirements for the final result are but based on the expected result in the question, either operator will do.

Comment: Apparently (see the OP's comment) `$push` is the right-thing-to-do

Comment: Yes, since the *$addToSet* add the element if and only if the final array does not contain the element itself, I tested the pipeline above using the *$push* operator, which works perfectly. 
Thanks guys :)